# ${}_nP_r$ versus $n^r$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If I had $n=2$ different symbols, how many $2$-symbol ($r=2$) "words" could I create?

If I had $n=5$ different symbols, how many $2$-symbol ($r=2$) "words" could I create?

Would I use the permutations formula or $n^r$?

Why?

Edit: Yes, you are allowed to repeat symbols in the same word.

Comment: Are you allowed to repeat symbols?

Comment: That depends: are we allowed to repeat the same letter in a word?

Comment: This may be a good read: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-differentiate-between-formulas-of-NCR-and-NPR

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: **Hint:**  Suppose you have two different symbols, $a$ and $b$.  If repetition is permitted, notice that you can form four words of length $2$: $aa, ab, ba, bb$. Observe that you have two choices for the first letter and two choices for the second.  Can you now answer your own question?

Comment: So, I'd use _nP_r for both. I think I see what I was missing now. Thank you.

Comment: That is incorrect.  See the answer I have posted.  I hope it clarifies the issue for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If repetition is permitted, then there are $n$ ways of choosing each of the $k$ letters of the word.  Hence, there are $n^k$ possible words when repetition is permitted.

Suppose our alphabet is $\{a, b, c\}$ and we wish to form words of length $2$.  Since we have three choices for each letter, there are $3 \cdot 3 = 9$ words that can be formed.  They are $aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc$.  Notice that $3^2 = 9$.

If repetition were not permitted, there are $n$ ways of choosing the first letter, $n - 1$ ways of choosing the second letter, $n - 2$ ways of choosing the third letter, and so forth.  In general, there are $n - (k - 1) = n - k + 1$ choices for the $k$th letter.  Thus, if repetition is not permitted, the number of words with length $k$ that could be formed is 
$$P(n, k) = n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - k + 1) = \frac{n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - k + 1)(n - k)!}{(n - k)!} = \frac{n!}{(n - k)!}$$
which is the number of permutations of $k$ objects selected from a set with $n$ objects, that is, the number of ordered selections of $k$ different elements of a set with $n$ elements.

Using the same alphabet as above, there are three ways to choose the first letter of a two-letter word, which leaves two ways to choose the second letter.  Thus, $3 \cdot 2 = 6$ words can be formed.  They are $ab, ac, ba, bc, ca, cb$.  Notice that 
$$P(3, 2) = \frac{3!}{(3 - 2)!} = \frac{3!}{1!} = \frac{6}{1} = 6$$
as expected.

See if you can now answer the two questions you posed above when repetition is permitted and when it is not.

Comment: Ah, I see. It helped me to review this, too: http://www.keithschwarz.com/talks/slides/fun-with-number-systems.pdf I was trying to discern why n^k would be used sometimes and the permutations formula elsewhere and I think I get it now. The key is whether or not repetition is allowed (which wasn't discussed in the text I'm looking at). The problems I initially posted were made up by me to try to think about it more, but if I were to solve them now, then I'd say...2^2=4 words for the first and 5^2=25 words for the second.

Comment: Those are the correct answers when repetition is permitted.